# Is this safe to use the host fragment/activity in an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-asynctask

My activity or a fragment in an activity uses an async task to do CPU-intensive work. I was wondering where inside the async task it is safe to use the host activity or fragment.

I guesss onPostExecute should be fine because Async task is designed to help UI threads, and I see examples that update UI in onPostExecute.

But is it also safe to do so in doInBackground? Is it possible during doInBackground that the fragment or the activity is destroyed?

Comment: why you do not check documentation on AsyncTask first?\

Comment: In developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html, it only says that an async task runs like a background task. In terms of its semantics, onPostExecute is called at the last step when it is still available to update UI. So, it kindof implies that the host UI should still be available during the entire process of an async task. So, doInBackground should be safe. What happens if a user kills the front-ground UI during the execution? Does runtime ensure that this will not happen until the async task is done? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your doInBackground() can call publishProgress() to send progress updates to the UI thread. Then you can override onProgressUpdate() and update the UI from inside that method.

Yes it is possible for your fragment and activity to be destroyed while the AsyncTask is running. You must check for that before updating the UI from the AsyncTask.

There's more information at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html